# Maven Build stuck at Creating Spec file

Tags: windows, bash, maven, rpm, kylo

I've been trying to build the kylo (ver 0.8.4) project using maven on my windows machine, using the new bash feature, and following the instructions on the [dev docs site](https://kylo.readthedocs.io/en/v0.8.4/developer-guides/KyloDeveloperGuide.html).

I'm running into this situation where there's a spec file being created, and its been stuck at that message for the last hour. I've attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VArPL.png)

Can someone help me with this please?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is where Kylo is building an RPM artifact for installing on RedHat type systems. It requires the rpmbuild package which is unavailable on Windows.

Please see the Kylo Developer Guide for more information:

> The assumption is that you are installing on a Mac or Linux box. You can do most activities below on a Windows box, except to perform a Maven build with the RPM install.

http://kylo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developer-guides/KyloDeveloperGuide.html

You have a couple options:

1) Build Kylo up to the kylo-install-tar module:

```
mvn -am -pl install/install-tar package -DskipTests
```

2) Try compiling within the Kylo sandbox or a Linux VM.